# os161 parent and child thread pid

Tags: operating-system, os161

Is anyone familiar with [os/161](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~syrah/os161/) and can answer a few questions for me?

How exactly does child pid, parent pid works.

I know that when you call `thread_fork()` you are creating another thread base on the current thread, the new thread should have a unique id for himself and a different file descriptor table.  While `sys_fork` create a child from `curthread`, the child is the same as the parent besides the pid. But I am confused in how pid and parent pid works.

This is my interpretation of the process table. There is only one process table for the whole system. For now I have `parent_pid` and `my_pid` for every thread.
-A parent thread can have multiple child, (by keep calling `sys_fork`).
-A child can only have one parent.
-Whenever `sys_fork` is called, a child is created and the `parent_pid` for this child is set to the pid of the thread who created this child.
-pid of 1 is for the boot/menu thread.

Am I even on the right track in understanding how process table works?

One last question:
For `sys_waitpid()`: Only parent can use `waitpid`? and they can only wait on their childs? Can a child use `waitpid` on a parent (or would this result in deadlock)?

I been searching around with Google, but I find so many contradictions, up till now I still can't find a clear answer to my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nothing of OS/161 -- but your description sounds a lot like a standard POSIX system. So, here's how your questions work with POSIX and hopefully they'll make sense for OS/161 as well.

Only parents ever call `waitpid()`. Applications are designed around this. The POSIX specification of `waitpid()` requires returning an error with errno set to `ECHILD` if the pid is not a child of the calling process.

Children can determine if their parent has died by checking their own `parent pid`: `getppid(3)`. If it is `1`, then their parent has died and their parent has been set to `init`. (`init` is prepared to reap *all* orphaned children when they die, so the process state doesn't linger and fill the system process table with zombie processes.) (Modern systems don't have a "process table" any longer, but the pids must be recycled and some process control information must remain in the kernel until `wait()` of some sort has been called to reap the process. That memory is too important to leave idle for long.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I have another question. Pids must be re-used? why can't I assign a new Pid to threads?

What I did for my Process table is whenever I create a new thread, I find the next available space on the table and add it in and then I loop thought all the thread in the process table to find the largest PID, add 1 to it, and put that as the pid for the newly created thread

Comment: Pids are stored with a fixed-size data type: typically 32 bits, though older systems used 16 bits. Thus you _eventually_ have to re-use pids, once you've had more than 32768 processes run on the system. Linux, for example, limits the maximum pid value to 2^22: after four million-odd processes, the numbers wrap around to `1` again. Since the actual _value_ of a pid doesn't matter, there's usually no mechanism to change the pid of a running process.

Comment: o ok that make sense. but just one more question. in os161, sys_exit(int exitcode) and sys_waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status)
http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~mtauraso/man/syscall/waitpid.html
http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~mtauraso/man/syscall/_exit.html

What exactly is exitcode and status. Right now i made it so every thread have a exitcode, 0 for being active, 1 when it is using sys_exit. Me and my partner read the manual page over and over again, but we are still very confused as to how they work. Hope you can help us again. Thanks

Comment: The exit code can be used to communicate general _success_ or _failure_ to a parent process. For a "simple" example, look to `grep(1)` -- it returns an exit status of `0` for "found a match" and an exit status of `1` for "no match found". `2` means there was an error. Other programs, like the shell, can use the exit status to determine future steps to take. Because `waitpid()` always sleeps until the child is dead, no parent can ever read the `0` "active" code you've designed.